# Finding primes with Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, math

I wrote a simple program in Java that I'm running with Eclipse to find prime numbers less than 1000.

Here it is, new edit:

public class primes {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("2");
    int n=3;  
    int d=2;
    While(n<1000);
    {
        if (n%d == 0){ //if d is a divisor n is not prime
            n=n+1; //try next number
            d=2; //reset divisor
            }
        else{
            if (d>n/2){ //if there are no divisors up to n/2 n is prime
                System.out.println(n);
                n=n+1; //try next number
                d=2; //reset divisor
                }
            else{
                    d=d+1; //try next divisor
                    }
        }



    }

}

private static void While(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I got it to run this time but it only prints 2 and 3. Is there a way to use this approach but make a modification?

Comment: You can't declare `n` and `d` like that. Your compiler will ignore anything after a `;` on the same line. Move `d` to the next line. Also, remove the `;` from `While(n<1000);{`

Comment: @emsimpson92 `int n=3;  int d=2;` is valid syntax and the compiler won't ignore `d`. Other humans will probably ignore it since it's pretty easy to miss anything after `;` though =]

Comment: @slaga You couldn't calculate prime numbers in one cycle. You need two, second cycle will check if the number divides on each of previously found primes.

Comment: Write a method that checks if the current number is prime.  If it is prime then return true, else return false.  Use that method to cycle through all of the numbers from 1 to 1000.  Something like 
while (numberToCheckIfPrime < 1000) {
            if (isPrime(numberToCheckIfPrime)) {
                System.out.println(numberToCheckIfPrime);
            }
            numberToCheckIfPrime++;
        }

Comment: `void While(boolean b) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub` Exhibit A for why people shouldn't learn to program using an IDE, right here, folks.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is all messed up. Using a semicolon will end the line and any code written on the same line after that is ignored.

It should look something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println(2); not sure what you're trying to print here
    int n=3;
    int d=2;
    while(n<1000)
    {
        if (n%d == 0)
        {
            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (d>n/2)
            {
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            else
            {
                d++;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void While(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

If it still doesn't do anything then it's because `d` is never > `n/2`.

Comment: Using a semicolon ends the *statement*. Another statement can follow on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int N = 1000;
        int[] primes = new int[N/2]; // N/2 is enough
        int cnt = 0;

        primes[cnt++] = 2;
        for(int i=3; i<=N; i++){
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for(int j=0; j<cnt; j++)
                if (i%primes[j]==0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (isPrime) primes[cnt++] = i;
        }
        primes = Arrays.copyOf(primes,cnt);  //reduce the size
        System.out.println(primes.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primes));
    }

}
```

It will give you:

```
168
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]
```